# Make fast query on foreign keys, django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a performance issue on the following szenario:

My models:

```
class Journey(models.Models):
    #...

class Station(models.Model):
    #...

class Connection(models.Model):
    station1 = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='station1')
    station2 = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='station2')
```

Now I arranged a list via a* that contains adjacent stations_ids on a journey (from a to b) and I need to get the matching connections. Ive used those 2 possibilites, but the both need the same time which can be more than 10 seconds for longer journeys:

```
for i in range(0, len(journey)-1):
    try:
        connection = Connection.objects.get(station1_id=journey[i], station2_id=journey[i+1])
    except Connection.DoesNotExist:
        try:
            connection = Connection.objects.get(station1_id=journey[i+1], station2_id=journey[i])
        except Connection.DoesNotExist:
                pass
    journey.connections.add(connection)

for i in range(0, len(journey)-1):
    s1 = Station.objects.get(id = journey[i])
    s2 = Station.objects.get(id= journey[i+1])
    if (Connection.objects.filter(station1=s1, station2=s2).exists()):
        connection = Connection.objects.get(station1=s1, station2=s2)
    elif (Connection.objects.filter(station1=s2, station2=s1).exists()):
        connection = Connection.objects.get(station1=s2, station2=s1)
    journey.connections.add(connection)
```

How can i make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write sql query directly instead django tools.
Try this code:

```
Connection.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM yourapp_connection WHERE station1={0} AND station2={1}'.format(s1,s2))
```

Instead of this:

```
Connection.objects.get(station1=s1, station2=s2)
```

Replase `yourapp_connection` to name of your connections table.

You can combine two if statement to one query:

```
Connection.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM yourapp_connection WHERE station1={0} AND station2={1} OR station1={1} AND station2={0}'.format(s1,s2))
```

This is might make it faster.